# Devise authentication token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

In devise, how do i access the authentication token of a user. When an ajax call initiates a user session, I need to able to get an authentication token out of the user. I've tried to do things like adding :token_authenticable in my model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

also adding attributes of names like :authentication_token, and :authenticity_token to attr_accessible. But every time i try to call authentication_token or this authenticity_token out of the user with user.auth ... i get errors like this

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authentication_token' for #<User:0x000001016b1140>
```

Sorry, i need to get this token to send with my ajax calls, (the last project i worked on i had an incredibly BOOTLEG solution where devise was nearly torn out of the application, i just need this damn token)

Comment: i had a similar problem, let me know if u find a solution, not good reading material available

Comment: token_authenticatable has been depreciated as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931952/devise-token-authenticatable-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

Answer (score 8):

This is fixed by including the `:token_authenticatable` module into the `devise` user model:

```
devise :token_authenticatable, ...
```

Also the method is defined on the class itself, not an instance. Call it as `User.authentication_token`.

See here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb#L61-63.

Comment: nice, sorry if i sound a little slow, but to check who a particular user is, should i make an attribute named auth_token and say user.auth_token = User.authentication_token. Then use this to verify who a user actually is. because it seems like devise is already making that parameter be sent whenever i change a view, but i cant manually do it with an ajax call

Comment: The method authentication_token exists on both the instance and the class.  Use instance method user.reset_authentication_token! to set the token (basically does user.authentication_token = User.authentication_token), devise should handle the actual verification part: "mysite.com/user/1/edit?auth_token=#{user.authentication_token}"