# Using the new Devise for authentication for a mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, mobile, devise

I am trying to implement user authentication using `Devise` for my `Rails`/`iOS` app. I am having trouble since I've mostly been a "*user*" of Devise and was using it for pure web apps so didn't need to bother so much with what goes on behind the scenes. Now that I have to build authentication for an API based app, it's entirely a different world.

I've read *every single* tutorial on the web that deals with this topic (most of them are outdated due to the fact that `token_authenticatable` has been deprecated) but still having trouble understanding what I need to do.

I also read the original `GitHub` gist talking about [this issue](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) and still don't understand what they are talking about.

I'm sure there are people out there just like me who've been just a "*user*" of `Devise` so don't really know what goes on behind the scenes.

Can anyone provide a concise solution to implementing an API based authentication system for a mobile app? I mean it can't be that complex, `Devise` used to be so awesome since all i needed to do was run `rails generate`, but this has been nightmare for me.

Comment: Is there something in particular that doesn't make sense in this guide: http://www.slideshare.net/apartmentlist/authentication-in-i-os-and-rails-using-devise

Are you having trouble on the Rails side, the iOS side, or both? What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1. Send login request to your devise controller. 2. Respond with the login auth token. 3. Store auth token in NSUserDefaults or keychain. 4. Use auth token to make user-private requests.

Comment: That slide uses token_authenticatable, which as I mentioned, is deprecated. By now I know the big picture, I just don't know how to implement it in detail because of all the complexities involved

Comment: See this post and thread on how to replace that one component of this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933419/614152

Comment: Sorry if I sent you back to the gist that you didn't find useful... If I may suggest an approach... Start off by building the user authentication in the deprecated manner. Then, go ahead and refactor the token generation to be up to date and more secure. This will get you 90% of the way there, and you can focus on the one component that is giving you trouble. You'll also gain a deeper understanding of devise in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have seen that post too but had ignored it because it didn't feel right to use the solution to support backward compatibility, but I guess I really don't have a choice. But I am confused why I have to go through all this trouble in order to use Devise. It used to be so simple, all i needed to do was rails generate and add some configurations and I had an authentication system. I mean I get why they had to do it, but I don't get why there isn't an elegant solution to this

Answer (score 3):

I am working on same things as you want,

for this you have to use token authentication rather than simple
Devise, add following gem in gemfile

```
  # Use device for authentication
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'simple_token_authentication'
```

follow documention [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication)

```
Use Api like this

curl -v https://example.com/users/sign_in -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"login": "7838712847" ,"password": "8489", "mobile_type": "ios", "mobile_key": "APA91bG6G4UvjeCWvb8mMAH1ZO3I-8FB3nkRPyCHnwZiXgd16HK18GgoV5n7gjJtZNs038iaFGutzdxnhes3WyaXEX52-xmOyvuEK8S1abBdpuhD9AD5bzLWeu-1Ow_yZRTVg3Nypz1z"}}'

I am using mobile number to login so customize gem according your need
```

please let me know if it is not working (mail me: er.mukeshsharma.rj21@gmail.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that works excellent for me, when using Devise for authentication in a Rails app. If tests for a token first (you can set the token by any iOS, Android, ... app) and falls back to the default authentication method for your web users.

### Rails

Add your own token to the user model, by adding an :api_token string column and fill that with a unique value per user. Using a Digest::SHA1 of some user data (like id + email) is a good starting point, but you can (and should) go as crazy as you like when it comes to generating a unique token.

Create a method for authentication over that token. You can add it to your main ApplicationController for easy access (don't forget to put the method in your private section of the controller);

```
def authenticate_user_by_token
  @api_token = request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']

  if @api_token.present? && @user = User.find_by_api_token(@api_token)
    sign_in @user
    return @user
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Next create a (private) method and chain this method to the devise before filter method you are using (like :authenticate_user! for example). Put it in the same controller as the method above for easy access;

```
def authenticate_by_token_or_devise!
  return authenticate_user! unless authenticate_user_by_token
end
```

Now Replace your current before_filter call from :authenticate_user! to the newly created one; :authenticate_by_token_or_devise!, like so;

```
before_filter :authenticate_by_token_or_devise!
```

Or, starting from **rails 4** ([Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action)), use before_action;

```
before_action :authenticate_by_token_or_devise!
```

### iOS

Now all you have to do is add that token to your iOS app. Depending on the framework that you use in your app, this might be different then the code below.

I use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in this example. This is how you set the Authorisation header token in your AFHTTPRequestOperationManager so it gets added to every request you make.

```
NSString *apiToken = @"your-token-here";
[[_manager requestSerializer] setValue:apiToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

### Optional

Additionally, you can create a before filter method that allows access to token-based authentication only (e.g. if you have a set of /api routes that you only want to be accessed using the token) like this;

```
def authenticate_user_by_token!
  if !authenticate_user_by_token
    render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized and return
  end
end
```

Comment: Seriously? Generate a static token for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, we also had to set up token based authentication for our webapp (for API access) - and we also stumbled upon the fact that it has been removed from Devise.

We went with [Simple Token Authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) which worked just beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

When I recently implemented an API, I grudgingly followed a suggestion to use [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki), a rack-based authentication gem. My sense was that an authentication gem that required you to write your own authentication was broken. But this gem provides just the right level of control. My only complaint is that the gem don't handle POST parameters well. [I was able to work around it](https://gist.github.com/mustmodify/f825c721fb7163d25ca3#file-warden-rb-L69-L89), but that kind of concern should be (IMO) handled by the gem.

Having used it, I highly recommend this gem for any scenario requiring non-generic authentication. Rolling your own authentication strategies is a joy because (a) it's pretty simple and (b) you aren't bound by other devs' assumptions.

To help you get started, [here is my config/initializers/warden.rb file](https://gist.github.com/mustmodify/f825c721fb7163d25ca3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the devise gem and doorkeeper gem to support web and mobile authentication.

For example, I used devise for signing up users and handling forget password and email confirmation flow. For mobile clients, I used the doorkeeper gem as a oauth2 provider to protect my apis. There are many oauth2 grant flows supported by the doorkeeper gem and I suggest you can take a look at those.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Example-Applications)! to get started